# How to copy predetermined multiple files in with_items in single Ansible playbook to diff target destinations?

Tags: ansible

Plz bear with me I am new to `Ansible`. I have a `tasks/main.yml` file like this as part of an effort to enhance. For now, I have to execute a playbook for each file separately to copy `A.jar` and `B.jar` one at a time. However I am trying to create an array to contain `A and B jar` files in advance and process one by one to copy it to two different destination folders in this playbook but struggling with syntax. Hoping to re-use `with_items`.

```
- name: Copy 
 copy:
   src: "/somePath/{{ name }}.jar"
   dest: "{{ item }}"
   remote_src: yes
 with_items:
   - "/pathTo/foo/"
   - "/pathTo/bar/"

# /pathTo/foo
A.jar
B.jar

# /pathTo/bar
A.jar
B.jar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`with_nested`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/nested.html) for looping,

```
- name: Copy 
  copy:
   src: "/somePath/{{ item[0] }}"
   dest: "{{ item[1] }}"
   remote_src: yes
  with_nested:
   - [ "A.jar", "B.jar" ]
   - [ "/pathTo/foo/", "/pathTo/bar/" ]
```

This iterates over each element in each list to copy all your source files (`A.jar` and `B.jar`) from the first list to all the destination directories listed in the second list.